# Scientific notation for scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with customers and their scores

```
Customer     Score
A              20000
B              25000
C              25000
D              25000
E               2000
F               2000
G              12000
```

I would like to plot a scatter plot which shows the frequency in a scientific notation.
Currently I have plotted the data above as follows

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df['Score'].value_counts().plot(ax=ax, kind='bar')
```

How can I transform axis in a scientific notation? For example, 10^1?

Comment: If the values are all in that range, why would you do that?

Comment: They should actually be x*100. I just omitted times 100 there. Please consider them as times 100 (then out of range)

Comment: [log scale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/log_test.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to format your yaxis to scientific notation:

```
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(True)
```